# proFTPD on my Plesk 12.5 (centOS 6.6)

Tags: centos, plesk, proftpd

I have an issue with proFTPD.
I can see it's installed, when I look in my plesk admin (in "Updates and upgrades").
But when I try to restart proFTPD through SSH - it says "proftpd: unrecognized service". But I can see the "files" in my Plesk controlpanel. I can't connect through FileZilla.

And I don't see proFTPD in "/etc/init.d" - does anyone have and idea why this is?

Please, I really need some ideas...
I might have gone blind on this :(

Answer (score 0):

proftpd running as xinetd process, you can restart it with:

```
/etc/init.d/xinetd restart
```

Error message `Server sent passive reply with unroutable address` points to server working behind the NAT, general advise is to [switch to "active" mode as described here](http://www.webuzo.com/blog/tag/server-sent-passive-reply-with-unroutable-address-using-server-address-instead) and pay attention to further error messages.

There maybe some other errors related to SELinux(try temporary disable it with `setenforce 0`) or iptables(or some intermediate firewall)

Comment: Hi Oleg - thanks for your asnwer - It did the trick!
Unfortunately, I still can't connect to my FTP via FileZilla - do you have any idea to what I can do?

I get the following - and cannot get any further:

Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Status: Logged in
Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Status: Server sent passive reply with unroutable address. Using server address instead.

Comment: Hi, @Kucko check updated answer. Maybe to switch to active mode?

Comment: Hi Oleg - So far so good, now I don't get the error above, but It still times out - I get the following now: Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Command: PWD
Response: 257 "/" is the current directory
Command: TYPE I
Response: 200 Type set to I
Command: PORT 10,0,2,8,238,6
Response: 200 PORT command successful
Command: MLSD
Response: 425 Unable to build data connection: Connection timed out
Error: Failed to retrieve directory listing
--
I'm searching through Plesk support aswell..